# Need to place urls in a config file in a website instead of placing in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently hitting my server with AJAX calls. I placed the end point URLs in a JS file in the project. Now, there is requirement to remove them from the JS file and somehow get it from a config file. 
In a java based application earlier, we used to place in config.properties and fetch with http requests. Here, in this case, it is a simple website. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Just build the file as you want and create a parser.

Orr maybe you can create a file with yaml format, and parse it.Because I really like yaml, perfect for config

http://yaml.org/

You can call this file config.properties I think if you want.

Answer (score 1):

With file.properties containing:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

and test.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="divOutput"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.get('file.properties', function(data)
{
    //alert(data);
    //$('#divOutput').text(data);

    // Process data
    var aData = [];
    var dataLine = data.split('\r\n');
    console.log(dataLine);
    for(var i = 0, length = dataLine.length; i< length; i++)
    {
        aData[i] = dataLine[i].split('=');
        aData[i][0].trim();
        if(aData[i][1]) aData[i][1].trim();
    }
    console.log(aData);
    $('#divOutput').text(JSON.stringify(aData));
});
</script>
```

you should get output: [["a "," 1"],["b "," 2"],["c "," 3"]]

jsfiddle of only Process data part:

```js
data = 'a = 1\r\nb = 2\r\n c = 3'; // from jQuery.get('file.properties', function(data) ...

//Process data
var aData = [];
    var dataLine = data.split('\r\n');
    console.log(dataLine);
    for(var i = 0, length = dataLine.length; i< length; i++)
    {
        aData[i] = dataLine[i].split('=');
  aData[i][0].trim();
  if(aData[i][1]) aData[i][1].trim();
    }
    console.log(aData);
 $('#divOutput').text(JSON.stringify(aData));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOutput"></div>
```